# django alphanumeric validator not work

Tags: django

i try to force the user to use only alphanumeric characters in a certain

field so i wrote the following code in the User model:

```
alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', message='Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, validators=[alphanumeric])
```

but i still can create:

```
User.objects.create(username="@@")
```

i don't want it to create something like it...

am i doing something wrong? did i wrote a wrong regex validator?

Answer (score 2):

I think your code should look like this:

```
username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, 
    validators=[
        RegexValidator(
            r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 
            message='Only alphanumericcharacters are allowed.',
            code='invalid_username'
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: @brad Updated the answer. It seems that you'll need to pass the `code` option too.

Answer (score 1):

Validating performs when you call model's `full_clean()` method or when you use ModelForm's `is_valid()`. Creating new model instance in shell or in view will not raise ValidationError. [More](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

Answer (score 0):

```
    user = CharField(
        max_length=30,
        required=True,
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex='^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$',
                message='Username must be Alphanumeric',
                code='invalid_username'
            ),
        ]

)
```

Source:[Django regex validator message has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760367/django-regex-validator-message-has-no-effect)